# load a module without evaluating its body at top level

Tags: racket

I have this file:

```
#lang racket

(provide install global-var)

(define global-var 'test)

(define (install)
  (set! global-var '(aaa)))

(install)
```

And I start the `repl`, typing so:

```
Welcome to Racket v5.3.5.
> (define global-var "test007")
> global-var
"test007"
> (require "test.rkt")
'(install)
> global-var
'test
```

Is it possible to load *only some definitions* from the file `test.rkt`, such that the loading does not change the value of `global-var`, only if I call myself `(install)`, after I load?

I want to use only the standard racket system, not outside packages that are not installed by default in racket.

Comment: Why not just delete the `(install)` line from the module? When would you want this to run when required?

Comment: This is the problem. I want to make some kind of lazy-loading, to load the module as a thunk at which I could send some messages after loading, and such that to evaluate some parts of it. For me it's more direct not to remove `(install)`.

Comment: I found this: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/load.html. I think that loading into a new namespace works, by evaluating what I need from that new nspace. I try it now, to see if this solves my problem. I am not sure if this changes the global namespace. In this case, not good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: probably not. You should think of a racket module as a pre-compiled bundle of code that exports certain functions. Any expressions at the top level (such as the call to 'install' here) are conceptually part of the module's setup; allowing a user to use the definitions without running the setup code would invalidate the assumptions of the module writer---not nice for the writer of the module.

To take an example, I have a sound library; requiring the sound library module initializes the sound playback. If there were a tricky way to load the module without running this code, my invariants would be violated.

Perhaps you can explain why it's inconvenient for you to edit the source code?

Comment: I have many files, which have dependencies in form of tree. Each file adds something to global-var, and some files _reset_ global-var. These files are the problem. I cannot load 2 such files that reset the global-var, and I have to copy-paste code. Yes, there are alternative to give the code other structure, but I would like to try to load a file in a different namespace, and from that namespace to execute only what it's useful in each case.

Comment: There was some discussion of this on #racket and someone pointed out submodules. As John explained, in Racket a module is the unit of requiring code. Submodules let you create, within the same source file, modules with different "lifetimes" (such as "test time", "doc making time", "main() time", etc.). It sounds like you should use submodules for "install time"? Finally, `dynamic-require` of things from those submodules might be another piece of the puzzle? This would be much less problematic than using `load`, AFAICT.

Comment: I studied the problem alone yesterday, and the best way I found is to make *main* and *test* submodules. The global variable would be reset only in the *main* submodule. Yes, yesterday somebody sugessted on #racket the use of submodules, and that was indeed the best answer to my question.

Comment: Using submodules, one does not need to change my code, only to move some part of it in different submodules.